# how to display special character on browser

Tags: java, html, xml, jsp, struts

I am trying to display content from database which has '&' and needs to be displayed in a browser. I have included:-

```
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=utf-8");
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

But still cant display the content to browser.

Comment: Check the  html source code of your question on this page.And you will know the answer.

Comment: @vikiiii  +1  The problem with too many web developers is that they do not know how to write HTML, and are either unaware of, or unwilling to use, a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) to check the output. :(

Comment: HTML special character conversion is what you are looking for: where ampersand symbol `&` will become `&amp;` in HTML. In PHP, you can use `htmlspecialchars()` function. In ASP.NET, you can use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode()` method

Comment: Same trick but using Javascript support in a web browser: http://sanzon.wordpress.com/2008/05/01/neat-little-html-encoding-trick-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `&` with the corresponding html entity `&amp;`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if you know the string might contain characters with special meaning to HTML, you want to encode it before displaying it. Look at the org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils method escapeHTML to see if that would work for you.